# Saving basic and extended stats of street network for multiple polygons using OSMNX

Tags: python, osmnx

Based on a given place name I use OSMNX to get street network graphs. I layed a grid over the street network dividing the network into multiple cells, for which each cell's polygon is stored in a geo-series object. With the following function I would like to store the basic_stats/extended_stats in a list and later convert it to a dataframe:

```
def stats_per_cell(geoseries):
network_stats = []
for i in range(0, len(geoseries)):
    try:
        # Get graph for grid cell -> row
        row = ox.graph_from_polygon(geoseries[i], truncate_by_edge=True)
        # Save basic stats for graph in list -> grid_stats
        grid_stats = ox.basic_stats(row)
        # Add grid cell id
        grid_stats['index'] = i
        print(grid_stats['index'])
        # Append in list -> network_stats
        network_stats.append(grid_stats)
        print(grid_stats)
    except:
        print('Error' + str(i))
        traceback.print_exc()
        continue
# Save entire list in df -> street features
street_features = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(network_stats, orient='columns')
return street_features
```

The code works fine, however after lets say 1000 iterations, it becomes very slow in comparison to the lists it had appended before. I tried to split the number of iterations for each run, reduced the dictionary from basic_stats to only a selection of keys, and assigned more memory to the process.
Still it takes quite a long time. I used Line_Profiler to get the time for each line:

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion what might cause the slow run time, how to increase the speed or what I could do to improve the code?

Cheers

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Which specific line is slow? How slow?

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I am new to scripting and was not familiar with this concept. I have added the results in a picture to my post. I had the function running for 2000 iterations. It appears that the `graph_from_polygon`command needs the majority of time. Can you explain to me why this takes so long? Do you have any suggestions on how to speed it up or should I look for some more resources to collect the data?

Comment: Did you turn on OSMnx logging? `ox.config(log_console=True)` You can see how long each step is taking. The `graph_from_polygon` function has to query the API, download all the data, model it, and process the topology. It can take a while for each study site.